# How do I get the value of .any? and when its true? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
@comment.body.scan(/@(\w+)/).flatten.to_a.each do|username|
   if @mentioned = User.where(:username => username).any?
    #@mentioned value??
   end
end
```

How can I get the value of @mentioned when its true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to get a `User` by username and check if there is one?

```
@comment.body.scan(/@(\w+)/).flatten.to_a.each do|username|
   @mentioned = User.find_by_username(username)

   if !@mentioned.blank?
    # @mentioned is a User model instance.
    @mentioned.username  == username             # => true
   end
end
```

Comment: check if there is one and get the username

Comment: Use `@mentioned.username` or just `username` within the `if` block.